# Nvidia Graphic not allowing boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, nomodeset

Hello and welcome to the toughest question on the internet! Brought to you today by this machine: Toshiba Qosmio x505-q830 core i7 720qm, 4gb DDR3, 320GB HDD, nVidia GTS 250M.

I have tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 desktop 64bit and Linux Mint 16 Petra w/ Cinnamon both produced same results. I am not dual-booting this with anything else, attempting to use a single OS (linux).

In order to run the liveUSB i have to boot with "nomodeset", once booted into the liveUSB install runs perfect and asks for reboot. I reboot, add nomodeset to grub and go from there. Do a update && upgrade. Install "Additional drivers" for nvidia (tried both version 331 and 309), after install i am asked to reboot, i reboot this time without nomodeset and i get a black screen with no activity. Force a shutdown, try to reboot with "nomodeset" and same frozen deal. All of the above repeat with identical results and error messages across ubuntu and linux mint. Below are a few links that may help:

dmesg, syslog, kern, xorg.0 log files -

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r6hjkuflhwoikae/nqS5ek7qxv

system specs as per Toshiba and verified by me -

http://support.toshiba.com/support/staticContentDetail?contentId=2428599&isFromTOCLink=false

BIOS version currently installed is latest available from Toshiba Support ( v 2.90 )

Answer (score 0):

Do you have optimus enabled in your laptop ? This means that you have both an intel / nvidia graphics chipset, that work together in certain ways to save power. It could be that your linux OS cannot find the nvidia chip , and hence cannot render anything on screen. If this is the case, a straightforward solution might be to try Ubuntu 14.04 , which seems to have the right updates for this to work. I would recommend checking [this link](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/more-work-to-support-nvidia-optimus.html) out , and installing nvidia-prime/ nvidia drivers (i personally use nvidia-319 drivers).

FYI: i had faced similar issues and solved them only yesterday (used beta2 version of 14.04).

Comment: i only have the dedicated nvidia card in the machine as listed in the specs. i will give trusty a chance though and report back.

Comment: Trusty did not have a different impact. same issues as mentioned above...(not sure why i couldn't edit my original comment.

Comment: while playing around with various parameters for boot i tried acpi=off and it allowed me to boot successfully into the liveUSB with trusty. I used https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI to debug the acpi issue further and found that i cannot boot with acpi=ht. So then what now ?

Comment: In this case , i am not sure about what is to be done . My problem was entirely different. I apologize for not being able to help out in this case!.